# Error: [Reanimated] `valueUnpacker` is not a worklet, js engine: hermes and Invariant Vilation

Tags: navigator, drawer, tsx

When I try to use the NavigationContainer I get the Reanimated valueUnpacker error, I try with different versions of Drawer and Navigation and I get the same error

```
// In App.js in a new project

import * as React from 'react';
import { View, Text,TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
//import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';


function HomeScreen(props: { navigation: { navigate: (arg0: string) => void; }; }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text style={{fontSize:20,color:"black"}}>Home Screen</Text>
      <TouchableOpacity style={{marginTop:20,width:200,height:50,backgroundColor:"blue",padding:10,alignItems:"center",borderRadius:10}} onPress={()=> props.navigation.navigate('Profile')}>
            <Text style={{fontSize:15,color:"white",textAlign:"center"}}>Go to Profiles</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}

function ProfileScreen(props: { navigation: { navigate: (arg0: string) => void; }; }) {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text style={{fontSize:20,color:"black"}}>Profile Screen</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity style={{marginTop:20,width:200,height:50,backgroundColor:"blue",padding:10,alignItems:"center",borderRadius:10}} onPress={()=> props.navigation.navigate('Home')}>
            <Text style={{fontSize:15,color:"white",textAlign:"center"}}>Go to Home</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }


  const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

  function MyDrawer() {
    return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator>
        <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
  }

  export default MyDrawer
```

It should have a navigation menu with different options but even if you try different versions it still fails

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it this way: I opened the android directory of the React Native project in Android Studio, then ran ./gradlew clean, followed by the ./gradlew build command again to solve the problem. If that doesn't work, you can try running 'Sync Project with Gradle Files' first.

Answer (score 0):

The following steps should fix the error

1. `npm install react-native-reanimated`
2. Add Reanimated's babel plugin
   Add react-native-reanimated/plugin plugin to your babel.config.js.

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    ... // don't add it here :)
  ],
  plugins: [
    ...
    'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
  ],
};
```

3. `npm start -- --reset-cache`
4. For ios,
   `cd ios && pod install && cd ..`
5. Finally, build the app again.

Comment: There is no mention of Babel in the question so I'm not sure your answer actually answers it.

Comment: I was having the same error recently. And tried the same steps I have mentioned and it worked for me. The steps I mentioned are an installation steps mentioned on the official documentation of react-native-reanimated